# Get Invalid signature from PDF on signing hash using private key from token

Tags: c#, itext, pkcs11interop

I am trying to sign a Hash of PDF Document that i receive from server. But it is showing "At Least one signature is invalid" in Adobe Reader. Can anybody suggest what is wrong in following code. Right now im just try implemented a code in one project with separated class.

CODE

***prepareHashToken.cs***

```
public class prepareHashToken
{
    public const string OUT_DIR = @"C:\Document\Doc1";

    private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
        protected byte[] sig;

        protected ICollection<X509Certificate> chain;

        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig, ICollection<X509Certificate> chain)
        {
            this.sig = sig;
            this.chain = chain;
        }

        public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            return sig;
        }
    }

    public byte[] EmptySignature(string src, string dest, IList<X509Certificate> chain)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;

        AcroFields acro = reader.AcroFields;
        List<string> sig_name = acro.GetSignatureNames();
        string field = "signature_" + (sig_name.Count + 1);
        Console.WriteLine("field : " + field);
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, field);
        appearance.Certificate = chain[0];
        IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 8192);
        Stream inp = appearance.GetRangeStream();
        Sha256Digest digest = new Sha256Digest();
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(inp, "SHA256");
        return hash;
    }

    public string createHash(string base64X509, string SRC, string TEMP)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(OUT_DIR);

        byte[] xx = Convert.FromBase64String(base64X509);
        X509.X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509.X509Certificate2(xx);
        X509Certificate m = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509);
        IList<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
        chain.Add(m);
        prepareHashToken app = new prepareHashToken();
        byte[] hh = app.EmptySignature(SRC, TEMP, chain);
        string hashString = Convert.ToBase64String(hh);
        return hashString;
    }
}
```

***SignHashToken.cs***

```
public PDFInfo SignPDF(List<string> Hash64, string pinNumber)
{
   using (Session session = slot.OpenSession(false))
   {
     session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, pin);

     List<ObjectAttribute> privateKeyAttributes = new List<ObjectAttribute>();
     privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY));
     privateKeyAttributes.Add(new ObjectAttribute(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_RSA));

     List<ObjectHandle> foundPrivateKeys = session.FindAllObjects(privateKeyAttributes);
     ObjectHandle privateKeyHandle = foundPrivateKeys[0];
     var mechanisms = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS);
     byte[] sourceData = Convert.FromBase64String(item);
     byte[] signature = session.Sign(mechanisms, privateKeyHandle, sourceData);
     result = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
   }
 }
```

***embedSignatureToken.cs***

```
 public class embedSignatureToken
 {
    public const string OUT_DIR = @"C:\Document\Doc1";

    private class MyExternalSignatureContainer : IExternalSignatureContainer
    {
        protected byte[] sig;
        protected ICollection<X509Certificate> chain;

        public MyExternalSignatureContainer(byte[] sig, ICollection<X509Certificate> chain)
        {
            this.sig = sig;
            this.chain = chain;
        }

        public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
        {
            return sig;
        }

        public void ModifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {}
    }

    public void CreateSignature(string src, string dest, byte[] hash, IList<X509Certificate> chain)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
            AcroFields acro = reader.AcroFields;
            List<string> sig_name = acro.GetSignatureNames();
            string field = "signature_" + (sig_name.Count);
            FileStream os = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create);
            IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(hash,chain);
            MakeSignature.SignDeferred(reader, field, os, external);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public void embedSigned(string base64X509, string hash64, string pin, string SRC, string TEMP, string DEST)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(OUT_DIR);

        byte[] xx = Convert.FromBase64String(base64X509);
        X509.X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509.X509Certificate2(xx);
        X509Certificate m = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509);
        IList<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
        chain.Add(m);
        embedSignatureToken app = new embedSignatureToken();

        byte[] hh = Convert.FromBase64String(hash64);

        app.CreateSignature(TEMP, DEST, hh, chain);
    }
}
```

***Base64 of pre-sign and sign***
[image: base64 of pre-sign and sign]
[Here i put a signed PDF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10rtDUPSAZA8CHyLmM-4tNiITnfJ5FZRw)

**UPDATE**

**SignHashToken.cs**

```
   byte[] xx = Convert.FromBase64String(CD.CertData);
   X509Certificate2 x509 = new X509Certificate2(xx);
   X509Certificate m = DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509);
   IList<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
   chain.Add(m);

   byte[] hash = Convert.FromBase64String(item);
   PrivateKeySignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(/*Asymmetric key */, "SHA256");
   string hashAlgorithm = signature.GetHashAlgorithm();
   PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, false);
   DateTime signingTime = DateTime.Now;
   byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
   byte[] extSignature = signature.Sign(sh);
   sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, signature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());
   byte[] encod = sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, tsaClient, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
   result = Convert.ToBase64String(encod);
```

Comment: What does `session.Sign` return? A PKCS#1 signature? A PKCS#7/CMS signature container? Please share a pdf signed by your code for analysis.

Comment: session.Sign does return a signed hash value. But, how to know what PKCS signature return? btw, i have update the post sir @mkl

Comment: I'll analyze your pdf later (probably on Monday in office) to see what exactly there is. If it merely is the naked signed hash, then your code is incomplete as it expects a full blown CMS signature container.

Comment: Hi sir @mkl , how about the sign? any info have you discover?

Comment: See above, *I'll analyze your pdf later (probably on Monday in office) to see what exactly there is*. And here it's just 7am.

Comment: Ok, apparently your signature service returns you the pure signature bytes. But your code claims (by using the `PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED` subfilter) that a full-fledged PKCS#7 / CMS signature container gets embedded. Thus you **a** sign the wrong hash (in CMS signature container the document is signed only indirectly, its hash being merely one value in a larger structure) and **b** inject the wrong data structure.

Comment: I'd like to show in an answer how to simply let iText handle the CMS stuff but your question and code don't clearly outline your use case. In particular, do you really require this deferred signing mechanism? Or could the first signing part immediately request the signature and embed it?

Comment: So the problem is sign the wrong hash and inject the wrong structure? . Yes i do required this deferred signing. Actually i did implement the code for signing using `p12`(same `pre-sign` and `post-sign` like code above but different in sign) and its successfully embed and get valid signature. In the real project, i also got same result. My application is just do signing(using c#), while the server part is prepareHash and embed (using java)

Comment: I try to modified a code from signing using p12, but im not sure if that possible or not because i don't know how to get Asymmetric key, see my update.

Comment: Hm, so it needs to be deferred... I'll look into that.